# Detecting a 4G capable device

Tags: android, detect, capability, 4g

I need to detect the 4G capability of the device.

How can I do that?

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: Sounds like you should rethink your design if you're relying on 4g. Why exactly do you need to detect 4G devices?

Comment: Well, it's a requirement coming from higher circles.. I just have to do it this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

4G is not something you can "detect", because 4G is a marketing term, not a technical term.

You can detect if an established connection is WiMAX using `ConnectivityManager`. I am not aware of Android supporting any other types of connectivity that are marketed specifically as 4G.

Comment: Yes, this is what I told them too. Without any success :)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same need.  What you really want is the current bandwidth.  You get that info from WiFi, but not mobile.  So the next best thing I came up with was to detect if the device is on 4G or not.  Unfortunately, it's not so simple.

Besides WiMAX, you can check if the device has a mobile connection using the `ConnectivityManager`.  If you detect a type of `ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE`, you then check the subtype.  If the subtype is `TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_LTE` or `TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EHRPD`, the device is 4G *capable*.

If the active network is subtype `TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_LTE`, then you are on 4G (but I haven't had the opportunity to verify this).  If you detect `TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EHRPD`, you have no idea if you are on 3G or 4G...at least I haven't been able to detect the difference yet.

There may be other subtypes that indicate a 4G capable device, but I haven't empirically verified them.

It's certainly not a definitive answer, but I hope it helps.